Import multiple rows from CSV to SQL Server and create a new ID for each one
I'm trying to extract several "agent" rows from a .CSV file and send them to SQL Server, but the .CSV file Num Contrat.csv may be the same for several agents, whereas it must be unique in SQL Server.
Example: there is an agent from my file:

Fields are Matricule / Name / DateDebut (starting Date) / DateFin (Ending Date) / ETP / Num Contrat
The last field is the most important, because it's the most problematic. It is identical in the .CSV, but must be unique in SQL Server.
Here's the logic I'd like to use in my code:

And here's how I try to get this result in my script:
try {
# Data
$matriculeContrat = $ligne.MATRICULE
$numContratOriginal = $ligne.'Num Contrat'
$abrTypContrat = $ligne.'Abr Typ Contrat'
$idEtablissement = [string]$ligne.'Num Dossier'

# Delete two characters and increment ContractNumber
$baseNumContrat = $numContratOriginal.Substring(0, [Math]::Max(0, $numContratOriginal.Length - 2))
$newNumContrat = $numContratOriginal
$suffix = 1

# Generate new contract number - Max 15 chars (doesn't work at all ?)
     while ((Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Contrats WHERE [Num Contrat] = N'$newNumContrat' AND Matricule = N'$matriculeContrat'" -ServerInstance $serverInstance -Database $database)[0].Column1 -gt 0) 
     {
         $newNumContrat = $baseNumContrat + ($suffix.ToString("D2"))
         if ($newNumContrat.Length > 15) 
         {
              $newNumContrat = $newNumContrat.Substring(0, 15)
         }
         $suffix++
     }

$insertContratQuery = @"INSERT INTO Contrats ([Num Contrat], Avenant, [Date début], [Date Fin], Type, [Temps Base], IDRégime, [Régime Mod], [Base contractuelle], RTT, [travail de nuit], [Règle équivalence], MultiEtablissement, [Matricule agent remplace], [Motif remplacement], [Convention collective], [Num contrat base], IDEtablissement, Matricule, [Report CPA], [Report Ancienneté], [Report CESS], Commentaire) 
VALUES (N'$newNumContrat', N'CONTRAT', $debutContratSql, $finContratSql, N'$abrTypContrat', $etp, N'MOD', NULL, $baseContractuelle, 0, $travailNuit, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, N'CCNT 66', N'$numContratOriginal', N'$idEtablissement', N'$matriculeContrat', N'0.00', 0, 0, NULL)"

@Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $insertContratQuery -ServerInstance $serverInstance -Database $database
Write-Host "Contrat ajouté pour le matricule : $matriculeContrat avec Num Contrat : $newNumContrat"

    } 
catch 
    {
    $errorMessage = "Erreur lors de l'ajout du contrat pour le matricule $matriculeContrat : $($_.Exception.Message)"
    Write-Host "Requête SQL problématique pour le matricule $matriculeContrat : $insertContratQuery"
    Add-Content -Path $sqlDebugFilePath -Value "Requête SQL pour le matricule $matriculeContrat : $insertContratQuery`nErreur : $errorMessage`n"
    }

The insert goes well for the first contracts (so I have 1 copy of each agent, with their "unique" original contract number without any suffix, however in Powershell I get this error several times:
Invoke-Sqlcmd : Violation de la contrainte PRIMARY KEY 
«PK_Contrats». Impossible d'insérer une clé en double dans
l'objet «dbo.Contrats». Valeur de clé dupliquée: (73065110180903).
L'instruction a été arrêtée.
Au caractère C:\Interconsult\Script_GetMS_Update.ps1:192 : 5
+     Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $insertContratQuery -ServerInstance 
$serverI ...
+     
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation : (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], 
SqlPowerShellSqlExecutionException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 


SqlError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand

Simply a duplicate primary key (Num Contract) error, so my incrementing doesn't work.
I've tried several things and I can't figure out how to solve my problem, if it works at all.
I hope everything is clear, thank you for your help.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.

Ok go it, i delete the prompt part !

Looks like you are generating duplicate contract numbers since you are using SubString. After few iterations it will start generating duplicates. You should not truncate.

NEW SOLUTION, updated based on comments:
use unused columns in the Database to store the Original Contract Number and pur a unique ID in the "Num Contrat" column.
Comment the code in abundance to explain the shenaningan.
OLD SOLUTION, not appliable to the live situation:

To be clear: you want to *replace* the last two characters in the "Num Contract" field? At this point, just add a progressive while importing.
$Counter = 0 
$UniqueContractArray = $CsvPath | Import-Csv | 
    Select-Object -Property 'matricule', 'Name', 'DateDebut', 'DateFin', 'ETP', 
        @{ 
            Name = 'Num Contract'
            Expression = { '{0}{1:d4}' -f $_.'Num Contract', $script:counter++ } 
        } 

This way you mantain the original contract number(potentially useful) while also know the last N digits are to differentiate them same-numbered contracts.
Replace the 4 in {1:d4} with how many digits you want\need or add more logic if you want to reset after some number(depending on how many same-numbered contracts you can expect, I guess)


I would have liked to, but the problem is that numbers in SQL server can only be 15 characters long, and some agents have +10 contracts. We should never reach 99+, but we never know...

But at this point you don't really have a contract number, if there is no reliable correltion between the number in the CSV and the number in the DB.
I suppose you cannot add another column on the DB to record the original contract number so you can make a 15digits unique ID?

I cannont but yeah, you just give me an idea, I can hijack an existing but unused column. It's not pretty, but it's doable, I think.

If you have unused columns: use those to store the Original Contract Number and pur a unique ID in the "Num Contrat" column. Yeah, it's a ugly hack and will require A LOT of Comments to explain what's happening pretty much anywhere the SQL is called, but it's doable if there is no other chance

If you aren't going to add, subtract, multiply, etc. contract numbers, just store it as a string (e.g., NVARCHAR(32)). Generally, if the number isn't used in math, store it as a string. With exceptions of course, such as INT/BIGINT IDENTITY fields and some others.

They are stored as string, like "VARCHAR(15)", but each one need to be unique. I think the best way to do that is to treat them like number and increment them one by one ?
